# difficulty with managing the error in Django - NoReverseMatch at

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views, django-urls

I need to make a query after two selection of the parameters.

1. Something is rong is - Error during template rendering - valoare_detail.html and it is writing -

   ```
   NoReverseMatch at /valoare/MICA/ Reverse for 'contract_list' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'valoare': 'MICA', 'tip': 'BUNURI'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['valoare/(?P<valoare>[A-Z]{4})/(?P<tip>[A-Z]{8})/$']
   ```
2. I can not manage the selection in template - contract-list.html.
3. Tell me the correct answer in code.

models.py

```
class Valoare(models.Model):
    VALOARE_CHOICES = (
       ("MICA","mica"),
       ("MARE","mare"),
    )
    tip_valoare = models.CharField(max_length=4, choices=VALOARE_CHOICES, default="MICI", verbose_name='valoarea contractului')
    file_name = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='contracte/templates/contracte/img/', verbose_name='img path')

def __str__(self):
    return self.tip_valoare


class Tip(models.Model):
    TIP_CHOICES = (
       ("BUNURI","bunuri"),
       ("SERVICII","servicii"),
       ("LUCRARI","lucrari"),
    )
    tip_contract = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=TIP_CHOICES, default="BUNURI", verbose_name='tipul contractului')
    file_name = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='contracte/templates/contracte/img/', verbose_name='img path')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tip_contract


class Contract(models.Model):
    valoare = models.ForeignKey('Valoare')
    tip = models.ForeignKey('Tip')
    data = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    file_name = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='pdf/', verbose_name='contract file name')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.CPV)

    class Meta:
       ordering = ["data"]
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.valoare_list, name='valoare_list'),
    url(r'^valoare/(?P<valoare>[A-Z]{4})/$', views.valoare_detail, name='valoare_detail'),
    url(r'^valoare/(?P<valoare>[A-Z]{4})/(?P<tip>[A-Z]{8})/$', views.contract_list, name='contract_list'),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Valoare, Tip, Contract


def valoare_list(request):
    valoares = Valoare.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'contracte/valoare_list.html', {'valoares': valoares})


def valoare_detail(request, valoare):
    valoare = get_object_or_404(Valoare, tip_valoare=valoare)
    tips = Tip.objects.all()
return render(request, 'contracte/valoare_detail.html', { 'valoare': valoare, 'tips':tips })


def contract_list(request, valoare, tip):
    valoare = get_object_or_404(Valoare, tip_valoare=valoare)
    tip = get_object_or_404(Tip, tip_contract=tip)
    return render(request, 'contracte/contract_list.html', {'valoare': valoare, 'tip': tip})
```

valoare_list.html

```
 {% for valoare in valoares %}
     <a href="{% url 'valoare_detail' valoare=valoare.tip_valoare %}">
           {{ valoare.tip_valoare }}
     </a><br>
 {% endfor %}
```

valoare-detail.html

```
 {% for tip in tips %}
       <a href="{% url 'contract_list' valoare=valoare.tip_valoare tip=tip.tip_contract %}">
           {{ tip.tip_contract }}
      </a><br>
 {% endfor %}
```

contract-list.html

```
 Valoare: {{ valoare.tip_valoare }} <br>
 Tip Contract: {{ tip.tip_contract }}
 (????? the result is to be the selection from model Contract by this two parameters in this template)
```

Tell me the correct answer in code.

Comment: I think the problem is here -     <a href="{% url 'contract_list' valoare=valoare.tip_valoare tip=tip.tip_contract %}"> - especial in the formation of tip=tip.tip_contract. In case I use pk - numeric variable, the result is Ok but I want to be showen [A-Z] format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NoReverseMatch at /valoare/MICA/ Reverse for 'contract_list' with arguments '()'
and keyword arguments '{'valoare': 'MICA', 'tip': 'BUNURI'}' not found.
1 pattern(s) tried: ['valoare/(?P<valoare>[A-Z]{4})/(?P<tip>[A-Z]{8})/$']
```

This error is pretty explicit:

- your template tries to generate an URI for the `contract_list` view.
- url files specifies that this view requires two arguments:

  - `valoare`, as a 4-alphabetic-character word
  - `tip`, as a 8-alphabetic-character word
- but the object you gave it has `BUNURI` as `tip`, which is invalid for this url.

Thus, no reverse uri matches.
To fix, you have to either correct your data so the object has a valid `tip` or, if a 6-character `tip` is valid, relax the requirement in the uri. For instance to tell it *from 4 to 8* characters, you would change it to `[A-Z]{4-8}`

Comment: I put for variable tip [A-Z]{6-8} but the error remain same.

Comment: Could you try `[A-Z]+` and see whether you still have the error?

Comment: perfect, it works. my question is about two parameter query in tempalte contract-list.html